# Aggregating the outcome of a MySQL sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please offer suggestions if this title doesn't make sense!

I am making a simple(ish) statistics query, a couple of columns I have are time started and the time ended when viewing an item. What I wanted to do was return the number of times that you could class a view of a certain item as a bounce.

Currently the query is able to return all the necessary information, it's fairly simple up to this point, but this part I'm having some trouble with.

This is i'm surethe wrong approach currently.

```
IF(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_ended) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_started)) < 5), 1,0) bounce
```

I need to try and take the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_ended) of each row and deduct it from the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(v.time_started), see if this value is smaller than 5 which i'm classifying as a 'bounce' and if so +1 to the bounce column.

I'm only returning 1 row of data, not sure how to execute this though, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jonny

**UPDATED CODE**

```
SELECT i.id, 
i.title, 
i.slug, 
i.buyer_id as buyer_id, 
i.date_added as date_added, 
a.slug as area_slug, 
COUNT(o.id) as offers, 
COUNT(v.item_id) as total_item_views, 
(COUNT(v.item_id) / COUNT(o.id)) conversion,

SUM(CASE WHEN v.time_ended - v.time_started < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

FROM item as i
LEFT JOIN offer as o ON i.id=o.item_id
LEFT JOIN viewed_item as v ON i.id=v.item_id
INNER JOIN area as a ON a.id=i.area_id

WHERE i.id=3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT Item
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN v.time_ended - v.time_started < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
FROM table
GROUP BY Item
```

From your updated code, you're missing a group by altogether:

```
SELECT i.id, i.title, i.slug, i.buyer_id as buyer_id, i.date_added as date_added, a.slug as area_slug, 
    COUNT(o.id) as offers, 
    COUNT(v.item_id) as total_item_views, 
    (COUNT(v.item_id) / COUNT(o.id)) conversion,
    SUM(CASE WHEN v.time_ended - v.time_started < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM item as i
LEFT JOIN offer as o ON i.id=o.item_id
LEFT JOIN viewed_item as v ON i.id=v.item_id
INNER JOIN area as a ON a.id=i.area_id
WHERE i.id=3
GROUP BY  i.id, i.title, i.slug, i.buyer_id, i.date_added, a.slug
```

Comment: Ok, I tried: SELECT .... (all columns and counts), 

SUM(CASE WHEN v.time_ended - v.time_started < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as bounce

FROM item as i
LEFT JOIN offer as a ON i.id=o.item_id
LEFT JOIN viewed_item as v ON i.id=v.item_id
INNER JOIN area as a ON a.id=i.area_id

WHERE i.id=3

ORDER BY bounce. Said I can't group on 'bounce'.

Comment: Remove bounce from your group by, you only group on non-aggregated fields.  Looks like your code got cut off so can't really tell if any other problems, if removing bounce from group doesn't work add code full code to your question.

Comment: Updated answer.  Is that the output you're looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks! +1! Query actually works without the group by clause.